# How do I use set_associated_object when the property I want to add is an unsigned int (enum)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

Now I'm doing it like this, is it correct? Any risks? Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)setNetworkStatus:(unsigned int)object{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(networkStatus), @(object), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

-(unsigned int)networkStatus{
    return (unsigned int)[objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(networkStatus)) integerValue];
}
```

I have changed OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN  to OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC in my code. Is there any problem?

Comment: Does it crash?  I would expect it to...

Comment: @trojanfoe No, it doesn't. When the return and parameter type is id, it does crash.

Comment: I would expect `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN` to cause issues.

Comment: I changed it to OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC

Comment: Hold on, you've just changed it?  What are you doing?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes i changed it. Because i realized that i have casted the int to NSNumber.

Comment: Well we cannot discuss the issues of code that you keep changing.  Close the question (and BTW you haven't cast the `int` to `NSNumber`).

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry. I have changed it back. And added more description below. I have wrap the int with @().